# How to make all widgets state to disabled in tk?

Tags: widget, tk-toolkit

Is there way to disable all widget in tk window with single proc? argument can be just initial toplevel path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a widget, you can get all of the children of that widget with [winfo children]. With a tiny recursive procedure you can act upon every widget in a tree of widgets. If you want to be lazy, you can usually also get a list of all widgets by doing [info commands .*]. That is often Good Enough, unless your application creates procedures or images with a name that begin with ".".

Most tk widgets accept a "-state" option, and those that don't can usually be ignored since state doesn't matter (for example, a frame widget). So, you can iterate over all the widgets and do something like [catch {$widget configure -state disabled}]. This won't work if you have unusual widgets that need to be enabled or disabled by some other means (such as the ttk button which has a "state" subcommand).

If you have a simple application using standard widgets, something like this may be Good Enough:

```
proc disable_all {path} {
    catch {$path configure -state disabled}
    foreach child [winfo children $path] {
        disable_all $child
    }
}
```

For precise control you can use "[winfo class $widget]" to get the class of the widget, and do different commands depending on the class.

Comment: in tcl recursion proc is it possible to save previous state of widget? So next time I can enable only which are disabled.

Comment: I was thinking to use
proc walkIntoTKTree {w} {
 set depth 0
 while {$depth < [llength [winfo children $w]]} {
   walkIntoTKTree [lindex [winfo children $w] $depth]
   incr depth;
 }
 puts "w=$w"
}

but ur soln is better